# Mitmproxy how to launch from script, and save dumps to file

Tags: python-3.x, mitmproxy

I am trying to figure out a way to launch Mitmproxy from a python script (which I have done) and save any traffic to a dump file (which i need help  with).

By googling, looking at mitmproxy git issues and reading example code, this is what I have so far:

```
from mitmproxy import proxy, options
from mitmproxy.tools.dump import DumpMaster
from mitmproxy.addons import core


class AddHeader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0

    def response(self, flow):
        self.num = self.num + 1
        print(self.num)
        flow.response.headers["count"] = str(self.num)


addons = [
    AddHeader()
]

opts = options.Options(listen_host='127.0.0.1', listen_port=8080)
pconf = proxy.config.ProxyConfig(opts)

m = DumpMaster(None)
m.server = proxy.server.ProxyServer(pconf)
# print(m.addons)
m.addons.add(addons)
print(m.addons)
# m.addons.add(core.Core())

try:
    m.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    m.shutdown()
```

Issue is, this creates an error `AttributeError: No such option: body_size_limit` which seems to be mitigated with `master.addons.add(core.Core)` but this core addon already exists in DumpMaster so that fires a different error.

Inspecting the addons that are currently loaded by `DumpMaster` i do see the save to file addon is loaded, but I am not clear how to access that so that any traffic that is going through the proxy, regardless if it is request, response, ws or tcp can be written to a dump file

Thanks!

Here is a redacted list of the addons that are loaded

- mitmproxy.addons.streambodies.StreamBodies object at 0x111542da0>
- mitmproxy.addons.save.Save object at 0x111542dd8>
- mitmproxy.addons.upstream_auth.UpstreamAuth object at 0x111542e10>

Answer (score 5):

just add those 2 lines after opts = options.Options(listen_host='127.0.0.1', listen_port=8080)

```
opts.add_option("body_size_limit", int, 0, "")
opts.add_option("keep_host_header", bool, True, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

your code snippet already runs a working proxy. However, the option to dump the recorded traffic into a file during runtime (`save_stream_file`) is part of the [`Save`](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/mitmproxy/addons/save.py)-Addon which is loaded by default **after** the [`DumpMaster`](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/mitmproxy/tools/dump.py) instance is created. Therefore, you need to set the `save_stream_file` option after creating the `DumpMaster` instance. Took me a while to figure it out as well but this worked for me, saving your output stream to a file named `traffic_stream`:

```
    from mitmproxy import proxy, options
    from mitmproxy.tools.dump import DumpMaster

    opts = options.Options(listen_port=8081)
    opts.add_option("body_size_limit", int, 0, "")
    pconf = proxy.config.ProxyConfig(opts)

    m = DumpMaster(None)
    m.server = proxy.server.ProxyServer(pconf)
    m.options.set('save_stream_file=traffic_stream')

    try:
        m.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        m.shutdown()
```

Hope it works for you as well!